# Global class not recognized laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to implement global functions by classes using laravel, heres my aproach:

Create a new class: `app/libraries/regex.class.php`:

```
class Regex{
    public static function isUsername($username){
        $regex = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/";
        if (preg_match($regex, $username))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

add the new library folder to `app/start/global.php`:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/libraries',
));
```

then use the function in a view called by a route:

```
 if(Regex::isUsername($_REQUEST['username'])==true){
    echo "<br><br>did it";
}
else{
    echo "<br><br>failed it";
}
```

if i put the `isUsername()` function at the top of the view that i use it in it works just fine but trying to make it global throws an error. however i get: `Class 'Regex' not found` on the line in the view where i try to use it. obviously it's not getting the class but i dont understand why?

edit: I was able to get it to work by adding `require app_path().'/libraries/regex.class.php';` to the end of the global file, it works now, but i would still like to know why the original atempt at autoloading didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your file according to the class it contains, so in this case it should be named `Regex.php`. The Laravel classloader looks for classes in files named this way.

You should also make sure you've added your libraries folder to the autoload.classmap section in composer.json.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I don't favor the force of naming convention that laravel enforces here though. What's the reasoning behing adding to composer.json? It works without doing it, just trying to figure out the quirks of laravel at the moment.

Comment: When you run composer it creates an autoload_classmap.php file, an index mapping classes to the files they're defined in. This works differently to Laravel's classloader, and would find your class whatever you named the file, but you need Laravel's classloader to be able to find it as well. I'm not sure of the exact mechanics (just enough to troubleshoot a problem) but I think the Laravel classloader is slower and there as a backup in development when you're changing files without running composer every time. The comment in global.php suggests that's the case.